# Question regarding Run command in Windows

Tags: external-calls

This line below in the cmd shell unzips the content of a zip file `D:\zips\test.zip` in the folder `C:\Users\mike\Desktop\test`:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe e -oC:\Users\mike\Desktop\test D:\zips\test.zip
```

If I use `Run` nothing happens with the ouput error 1:

```
Run["C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe e -oC:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\test D:\\zips\\test.zip"]
```

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but it's worth trying RunProcess. Note that you need to separate the executable name and its argument (unlike with Run).

Comment: I suggest first doing some tests such as `Run["echo testing > test.txt"]` which should create a text file in your Documents folder.

Comment: You have to escape quotes around the full executable path as described [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00457.html).  Something like Run["\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" -h"] should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion of my comment.

With its use of backslashes and spaces in directory names, the Windows OS a bit of an odd ball.  If you open a CMD prompt and try to execute the 7z.exe help (-h) without quotes, then I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Tim>c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe -h
'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now, the CMD prompt will automatically add quotes if you start typing a path to an executable and these quotes will need to be represented in the Run[] function.  The actual CMD prompt will look like this

```
C:\Users\Tim>"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -h

7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive....
```

The following *Mathematica* code should execute 7z.exe help and read the output.

```
outputfile = CreateFile[];
Run["\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" -h >>"  <> outputfile];
stext = OpenRead[outputfile];
ReadString[stext]
Close[stext];
DeleteFile[outputfile];
(* 7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark *)
```